# Suppress date and column heading in googlefinance historical data

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm attempting to get a column of data which represents the highest stock price for a given stock beginning on an arbitrary date, through today.  I have a column of ticker symbols in column A, and a purchase date in column B.  I want to populate column C with the highest stock price for that stock since the purchase date.

| Symbol | Purchase date | High since purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IBM | 1/1/2023 | (googlefinance formula) |
| TSLA | 5/1/2023 | (googlefinance formula) |

I'm trying:

=GOOGLEFINANCE(a2,"high",b2,today(),"weekly")

or more literally:

=GOOGLEFINANCE("IBM","high","1/1/2020",today(),"weekly")

What that returns is two columns of data, one for date and the other for the requested value, each with column headers, with a separate row for each date and associated value.  It looks like:

| Symbol | Purchase date | High since purchase |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IBM | 1/1/2023 | #REF |  |
| TSLA | 5/1/2023 | Date | High |
|  |  | 4/14/2023 16:00:00 | 191.58 |
|  |  | 4/21/2023 16:00:00 | 189.69 |
|  |  | 4/28/2023 16:00:00 | 165.65 |

It only processes the last ticker in the list, because the higher ones would overwrite the lower ones.

I don't need the date or the column headers; what I need is ONLY the highest value returned for the entire specified date range.  I have a couple hundred different ticker symbols in column A, so I don't want to try to muck around with hidden rows and columns - I just need an answer in a single cell, like this:

| Symbol | Purchase date | High since purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IBM | 1/1/2023 | 147.18 |
| TSLA | 5/1/2023 | 191.58 |

I also tried a max() wrapper around the entire function, which does return a single value, but unfortunately it's always a date, because the number of days since the number of days since 1900 is pretty much always going to be more than any stock price, even Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(a="",,max(choosecols(googlefinance(a,"high",b,today(),"weekly"),2)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation, this will do this:

`=MAX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "high", "1/1/2021", today()), "SELECT Col2"))`